# Can I use Enums in this scenario?

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

Let's say there is a Flower abstract class which can be either from the SUMMER, SPRING or ALL_SEASONS type. Now a flower like Violet can be either of the SUMMER OR SPRING seasons. How can I represent this in Java? I first tried to implement it using Enums but got stuck at this point.

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you? Why doesnt the `Violet` have some `Season type;` which u set to the correct season? For example via a constructor `this.type = type;` and then the user gives the correct season for the current flower `new Violet(Season.SUMMER)` etc?

Comment: [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) maybe.

Comment: Defining the possible seasons as an `enum` is perfectly fine. However, a single class attribute `private Season season` is obviously not sufficient if there are `Flower`s that may have more than one `Season`. Use a `List<Season>` or even a `Set<Season>` instead as a first naive approach.

Comment: @Zabuza it has to be specifically implemented so it can be either of Summer or Spring season in the case of Violet, and the instrcutor specifically made it as a separate request capitalizing it all which kind of suggests to me that he wants enumeration to be used here.

Comment: @deHaar thank you I think I will try that.

Comment: Well, a specific `Violet` instance might have one season attribute. But you can of course remember the set of possible seasons in a `Set<Season>`, use `EnumSet` as efficient implementation.

Comment: @DA you're welcome, see the answer given by *heyhoo*, it is basically what I meant. Use an `EnumSet` as Zabuza suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your needs is to implement a Flower class which have seasons, 
I implemented a solution, is not the best, but it reveals the basic OOP inheritance mecanism and enums, ihope it will help you

First, the season enum

```
 public enum Season{
        SUMMER, SPRING, WINTER, AUTUMN;

        public static List<Season> allSeason(){
            return Arrays.asList(values());
        }
    }
```

next the abstract class Flower

```
public abstract class Flower {
    abstract List<Season> seasons();
}
```

Then two classes that extends Flower and must define the seasons behaviour

```
class Poppy extends Flower{

    @Override
    List<Season> seasons() {
        return Arrays.asList(Season.SPRING, Season.SUMMER);
    }
}

class Anthurium extends Flower{

    @Override
    List<Season> seasons() {
        return Season.allSeason();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a `Set` instead of a `List` here. And as efficient implementation, take `EnumSet`.

Comment: As i said is a basic implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your requirements from your post,
you do not have a requirement for three seasons.
Instead you have a requirement for "flowering seasons".
The list of "flowering seasons" appears to be SUMMER,
SPRING,
SUMMER_AND_SPRING,
ANY_SEASON.

Consider the following:

1. Understand your requirements.
2. Build a solution that matches the requirements.

Based on your post,
you appear to have performed those steps in reverse
(built a solution then reviewed requirements).